# Merging several workbook sheets into target worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Using MS-Excel 2007, I noticed that in [this](http://quadexcel.com/merge-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-spreadsheet-vba/) code, I noticed that when run the first row of the target is always empty. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code in your question, as links can break.

Comment: Because of this line: `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`. It looks for the last used row in column A and then moves one row down which is the first empty row (except one case: when the whole sheet is empty then it fails).

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the code in that link is very much **not** [best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201704060943470120326).

Comment: Corker: it uses `.xlsx` files in the example, yet uses `Range("A65536").End(xlUp)` instead of `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`

Comment: @SteveES, I should have included my code to be more precise. The link you have provided is very good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
```

you can use something like that

```
Dim LastUsedCell As Range
Set LastUsedCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

If IsEmpty(LastUsedCell) Then
    LastUsedCell.PasteSpecial
Else
    LastUsedCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End If
```

to start with row 1 on an empty sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this option.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Post back if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thank you. I was more interested in understanding the problem with the code referenced in the question.